# What self defense items are allowed in India?

Tags: india, safety

I am planning on traveling with my family to India, mostly west side up to Goa, by trains and public transport. I am a firm believer that God protects those who protect themselves, hence the question.

What sort of hidden self-defense (pepper-spray, tasers) items are legal, also where to get them?

Comment: just to add, as long as you plan to go to legal places and places where there are a lot of people , you should not need any self defense items.

Comment: @NigelFds Hi, it's for my wife, I usually rip throats with my bare hands https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kFowuMIPF_g/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: lol , same applies to her

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, carrying Pepper-spray is legal in India. You can also carry knives (with length less than 5 inches). However, you might be stopped by the police during the security check if you are taking the subway in Delhi or other cities. You should always be ready with an explanation. Since you will be in Goa, there shouldn't be any problem as you don't have to go through the security check when you take a train.

Talking about tasers, you are not allowed to have them and only police officers are allowed to carry tasers as far as I know.

Comment: Knives are attacking weapons, not self defence.